# Get Directions API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have implemented some options on my google map, but I am having trouble on GET DIRECTIONS part. I have read many answers, and have implemented in many ways, but still can't figure out what's wrong. Hope you can help me:

Am trying to Get Directions from: location of the user (using geolocation), to: one clicked place.

I have implemented all of the above correctly, but something's wrong with my Directions code:

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize()
{
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
//some styles
var mapProp = {
//disableDefaultUI:true,    
zoom:14,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
  mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
 },
scrollwheel: false,
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {/*zoom on the left*/
style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
            }
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
var destinationmarker;

function placeMarker(destination) {
if ( destinationmarker ) {
destinationmarker.setPosition(destination);
} else {
destinationmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: destination,
  map: map
});

}
$("#end").val(destination.lat()+","+destination.lng());

}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
placeMarker(event.latLng);

});
// some markers from db
//below is the location of the user with a marker
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
position: pos,
animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
icon:'ktuugeo.png',
});

marker.setMap(map); 

$("#start").val(pos.lat()+","+pos.lng());
google.maps.event.addListener(marker);

//supposedly the route function, set to execute on change
function calcRoute() {
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var final = document.getElementById("end").value;
var request = {
  origin: start,
  destination: final,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
 };
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
 }
 });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

<body><div id="googleMap"></div>
<div id="dire" >
<textarea cols="20" rows="5" id="start" name="start"></textarea>
<textarea cols="20" rows="3" id="end" name="end" onchange="calcRoute();"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
```

That's all I guess. I have skipped some parts which are do not affect

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't guarantee this is the only detail to fix, but at least I can tell you that calcRoute is expecting objects as origin and destination. You're feeding it a string.

If you already know the values of `pos` and `destination` (you used them to draw both markers) then use them again instead of storing the positions as strings in DOM elements.

```
function calcRoute(pos,destination) {
    var request = {
        origin: pos,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: I missed setting the directionsDisplay map attribute.

Here, I left a working example to you: http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/acad781594f9976839c3

Comment: the problem is that the coordinates are stored this way (xx.xxxx, yy.yyyy). Including brackets. I guess that is a problem and that's why I had to store it in another variable and filter.

Comment: If that was the case, then neither origin's marker nor destination marker would display. Are they displaying?

Comment: By the way, do I have to do anything related to Google Api Console?

Comment: Nope, you're not doing anything that involves authentication.

Comment: I understand. Actually that was my first try but nothing happened, exactly as you wrote it. I just tried it again and no result yet. And yes, the markers both appear on the map

Comment: you broke the rules a programmer: Never show the final algorithm. But since this is scripting, it doesn't count. Thanks a lot!! :))